# Associations in test fixtures inside rails mountable engine

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have encountered a problem during unit testing of my fresh new mountable engine.

I have two basic models:

```
module Ads
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name :categories
    has_many :ads
  end
end

module Ads
  class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name :ads
    belongs_to :category
  end
end
```

It works perfectly fine in rails console.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > c = Ads::Category.create(title: 'foo')
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 22 Nov 2011 15:34:41 UTC +00:00], ["title", "foo"], ["updated_at", Tue, 22 Nov 2011 15:34:41 UTC +00:00]]
(18.0ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Ads::Category id: 2, title: "foo", created_at: "2011-11-22 15:34:41", updated_at: "2011-11-22 15:34:41"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > c.ads.create(title: 'bar')
(0.6ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "ads" ("category_id", "created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["category_id", 2], ["created_at", Tue, 22 Nov 2011 15:34:43 UTC +00:00], ["title", "bar"], ["updated_at", Tue, 22 Nov 2011 15:34:43 UTC +00:00]]
(16.8ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Ads::Ad id: 2, title: "bar", category_id: 2, created_at: "2011-11-22 15:34:43", updated_at: "2011-11-22 15:34:43">
```

I moved on to a unit test:

```
# test/unit/ads/category_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

module Ads
  class CategoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    # by default it searches in dummy app, is there any cleaner way to change this?
    self.fixture_path = Rails.root.parent + "./fixtures/ads" 
    fixtures :categories, :ads

    test "should find cars" do
      assert_equal 1, Category.where(title: 'Cars').count
    end
  end
end

# test/fixtures/ads/categories.yml
cars:
  title: Cars

# test/fixtures/ads/ads.yml
foo:
  title: Foo
  category: cars
```

When i run unit tests:

```
rake app:test:units
```

It ends up with error during populating test db:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "category" of relation "ads" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "ads" ("title", "category") VALUES ('Foo', 'cars...
```

It seems like ads<->categories association' is ignored.
Same approach works perfectly fine in a standalone rails app.
My question is: what am I doing wrong?
The side question is if there is a cleaner solution to change fixtures path?

Rails: 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue but with a Rails 3.0 engine. I couldn't fix it properly, but as a work around I did this.

Instead of:

```
category: cars
```

Do:

```
category_id: <%= Fixtures.identify(:cars) %>
```

This works, because the ID is actually a hash of the label. And Fixtures.identify is what does that hashing.